# PHP script running in XAMPP and not working in IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a problematic PHP script.

The script is working fine in **XAMPP** but I need it in **IIS 8.5** and there are several errors (some of them I've managed to handle).

I've tested on same Win Server 2012 R2 and if script is in C:/Xampp/htdocs/ProjectFolder/send.php and I run it at `localhost:88/ProjectFolder/send.php` (XAMPP is on port 88) is working fine. If same script that is now `C:/inetput/wwwroot/ProjectFolder/send.php` and I run it at `localhost:80/ProjectFolder/send.php` (IIS is on port 80) is not working.

The script is here ([PHP script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rBF0.png))

When run the script in IIS, this is first error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. 
Full screen of error here ([First error in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKLrn.png))

I added 2 Handlers in IIS, at server level: Handler Mappings-->Add Module Mapping
- first handler request path is *.html and module FastCgiModule, with executable php-cgi (see image [html handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqpoH.png) ) and Request Restrictions (Mapping Invoke Handler unchecked - see image [Mapping tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weND5.png), Verbs all verbs - see image [Verbs tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCpqz.png), and Access None - see image [Access tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCBRl.png))
- second - same for php (see image - [html and php Handlers added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvBTy.png))

I run the script again (after IIS restart) and I got following error:
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Error 2 - see image [Second error in IIS I cannot handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju1to.png)

Here I got stacked. Please advice. Thank you very much!